# How to delete many variables with lower case names, Python 3.7.2?

Tags: python, frame

I have a panda data frame that has ~5200 columns. ~1300 of them have lower case character in their names. These are the variables I want to delete from the final data frame.  The remaining variables all have upper cases in their names. This is the group of variables I like to keep. Is there a quick way to program to capture the ~1300 into a list? to be used for df.drop(column=....)?

Another question: is it possible to drop variables by short hands? For example, 10 variables all begin with 'D1_". Can we write something like "D1_:", instead of spelling out their full names?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you're working with, an example of the rows you want to keep, and also an example for the rows you would like to remove.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to move columns the names of which contain lower case and keep those the names of which are all upper case.

Comment: You literally have added nothing with that comment. You just reiterated what your question already says. What i meant was for **YOU** to **EDIT IN** the actual **CODE** you're working with, coupled with examples of the dataframe you're working with.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have code to share to begin with. The only code I have is the regular code like: df.drop(columns=['d1','d2'....'v1325'], inplace=True). There are ~1300 features between d1 and v1325. I am just curious if anybody has some idea how to write elegant so I don't have to labor to list all ~1300 features in the cell. It does  not take a lot of time to do it but looks ugly. I doubt listing the entire ~1300 features here is going to make any difference as far as elegant idea is concerned. Thanks.